# Cannot find great analytics library for android

Tags: android, crash-reports, flurry, crittercism

I really like to use flurry for analytics, however crash reports provided by the flurry are pretty ugly and short.
So i decided to use crittercism for crash reports.
And now these libraries takes 0.5 mb of my 1.4 app so it's pretty sad for me ;(

Wondering if someone can advise me all in one tool (analitics + crash reports), desirable with a feaututre of specifying the time to send the data(analytics + crash reports).

Also it would be great if the tool can work with my server(i.e. send data on my private server, not 3-rd party)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry will soon release an SDK version having Full Stack Trace crash reporting.
(Disclaimer: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Answer (score 0):

Google Play has a build in feature to create crash reports, and app statistics. If the size of the lib / not 3-rd party are your reasons for not being happy with flurry, why dont you use these features?

You can find them on the Google play developers webpage..

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do crash reporting other than flurry or google play reporting.

1. [Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously. See [BasicSetup](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) for a step-by-step installation and usage guide.
2. [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/) provides reliable crash reporting for both beta and released apps.  ITs similiar to flurry, but the crash reporting is much much prettier.

Overall these are both pretty damn good and I would recommend either one.

If you want a smaller filesize apk, have a look adding [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to your build routine. The [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.